# JSON Parsing in Android POJO class

Tags: android, json, retrofit, rest

For the Below  Reponse,But i am getting the error.

JSON Response.

```
[
    {
        "accountId": "51d44c1e44aec7ccda63f960",
        "id": "4e74fdf0-f428-11e9-b107-42010a9a0007",
        "name": "test edit asset group1 ",
        "description": "New Asset-group is updatring",
        "assets": [
            "4a51bcc0-263e-11ea-83e0-42010a9a0007"
        ],
        "beacon": null,
        "assetNames": null
    },
    {
        "accountId": "51d44c1e44aec7ccda63f960",
        "id": "518d8890-f428-11e9-b107-42010a9a0007",
        "name": "test edit asset group2 ",
        "description": "New Asset-group is updatring",
        "assets": null,
        "beacon": null,
        "assetNames": null
    },
    {
        "accountId": "51d44c1e44aec7ccda63f960",
        "id": "8b1176b0-3b88-11ea-b11f-42010a9a0007",
        "name": "test",
        "description": "test",
        "assets": [
            "e4a7d360-5c7e-11ea-b6b9-42010a9a0007"
        ],
        "beacon": null,
        "assetNames": null
    },
    {
        "accountId": "51d44c1e44aec7ccda63f960",
        "id": "9af47750-f62b-11e9-b6ae-42010a9a0007",
        "name": "test create asset for create asset group ",
        "description": null,
        "assets": null,
        "beacon": null,
        "assetNames": null
    },
    {
        "accountId": "51d44c1e44aec7ccda63f960",
        "id": "abc",
        "name": null,
        "description": null,
        "assets": [
            "d34e6d90-92c0-11ea-825d-42010a9a0007",
            "d6a62410-92c0-11ea-825d-42010a9a0007",
            "da153320-92c0-11ea-825d-42010a9a0007"
        ],
        "beacon": null,
        "assetNames": null
    },
    {
        "accountId": "51d44c1e44aec7ccda63f960",
        "id": "ba5d3030-f493-11e9-b107-42010a9a0007",
        "name": "test edit asset group1 ",
        "description": "New Asset-group is updatring",
        "assets": null,
        "beacon": null,
        "assetNames": null
    },
    {
        "accountId": "51d44c1e44aec7ccda63f960",
        "id": "bd7a9cd0-f493-11e9-b107-42010a9a0007",
        "name": "test edit asset group2 ",
        "description": "New Asset-group is updatring",
        "assets": null,
        "beacon": null,
        "assetNames": null
    },
    {
        "accountId": "51d44c1e44aec7ccda63f960",
        "id": "cc62c610-f62c-11e9-b6ae-42010a9a0007",
        "name": "test edit asset group1 ",
        "description": "New Asset-group is updatring",
        "assets": null,
        "beacon": null,
        "assetNames": null
    },
    {
        "accountId": "51d44c1e44aec7ccda63f960",
        "id": "cf3ce820-f62c-11e9-b6ae-42010a9a0007",
        "name": "test edit asset group2 ",
        "description": "New Asset-group is updatring",
        "assets": null,
        "beacon": null,
        "assetNames": null
    },
    {
        "accountId": "51d44c1e44aec7ccda63f960",
        "id": "d9783b00-f62c-11e9-b6ae-42010a9a0007",
        "name": "test edit asset group1 ",
        "description": "New Asset-group is updatring",
        "assets": null,
        "beacon": null,
        "assetNames": null
    },
    {
        "accountId": "51d44c1e44aec7ccda63f960",
        "id": "dc8cce00-f62c-11e9-b6ae-42010a9a0007",
        "name": "test edit asset group2 ",
        "description": "New Asset-group is updatring",
        "assets": null,
        "beacon": null,
        "assetNames": null
    },
    {
        "accountId": "51d44c1e44aec7ccda63f960",
        "id": "dd6102c0-92c0-11ea-825d-42010a9a0007",
        "name": "test edit asset group1 ",
        "description": "New Asset-group is updatring",
        "assets": [
            "d34e6d90-92c0-11ea-825d-42010a9a0007",
            "d6a62410-92c0-11ea-825d-42010a9a0007"
        ],
        "beacon": null,
        "assetNames": null
    },
    {
        "accountId": "51d44c1e44aec7ccda63f960",
        "id": "e0b11820-92c0-11ea-825d-42010a9a0007",
        "name": "test edit asset group2 ",
        "description": "New Asset-group is updatring",
        "assets": [
            "d6a62410-92c0-11ea-825d-42010a9a0007",
            "da153320-92c0-11ea-825d-42010a9a0007"
        ],
        "beacon": null,
        "assetNames": null
    },
    {
        "accountId": "51d44c1e44aec7ccda63f960",
        "id": "ea35c870-c27b-11e9-a265-42010a9a0007",
        "name": "gr1",
        "description": "",
        "assets": [
            "3d9cd800-2636-11ea-83e0-42010a9a0007",
            "68d07130-260e-11ea-83e0-42010a9a0007"
        ],
        "beacon": null,
        "assetNames": null
    },
    {
        "accountId": "51d44c1e44aec7ccda63f960",
        "id": "ef799780-c27b-11e9-a265-42010a9a0007",
        "name": "gr2",
        "description": "",
        "assets": null,
        "beacon": null,
        "assetNames": null
    }
]
```

My Pojo class Creation is as follows.
API interface.

```
Call<VoAssetGroup> getBeaconAssetGroup1(@Path("id") String id, @Header("ManagedAccountId") String ManagedAccountId);
```

Pojo class Creation
VoAssetGroup

```
package com.succorfish.installer.Vo;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;

public class VoAssetGroup implements Serializable {

    String accountId="";
    String id="";
    String name="";
    String description="";


    List<VoAssetGroupassets> assets;
    VoAssetGroupbeacon beacon;
    VoAssetGroupassetsassetNames assetNames;


    public String getAccountId() {
        return accountId;
    }

    public void setAccountId(String accountId) {
        this.accountId = accountId;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public List<VoAssetGroupassets> getAssets() {
        return assets;
    }

    public void setAssets(List<VoAssetGroupassets> assets) {
        this.assets = assets;
    }

    public VoAssetGroupbeacon getBeacon() {
        return beacon;
    }

    public void setBeacon(VoAssetGroupbeacon beacon) {
        this.beacon = beacon;
    }

    public VoAssetGroupassetsassetNames getAssetNames() {
        return assetNames;
    }

    public void setAssetNames(VoAssetGroupassetsassetNames assetNames) {
        this.assetNames = assetNames;
    }

}
```

VoAssetGroupassets class

```
package com.succorfish.installer.Vo;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;

public class VoAssetGroupassets implements Serializable {
   String assetsArray="";

    public String getAssetsArray() {
        return assetsArray;
    }

    public void setAssetsArray(String assetsArray) {
        this.assetsArray = assetsArray;
    }
}
```

VoAssetGroupbeacon class

```
package com.succorfish.installer.Vo;

import java.io.Serializable;

public class VoAssetGroupbeacon implements Serializable {
    String beacon="";

    public String getBeacon() {
        return beacon;
    }

    public void setBeacon(String beacon) {
        this.beacon = beacon;
    }
}
```

VoAssetGroupassetsassetNames class

```
package com.succorfish.installer.Vo;

public class VoAssetGroupassetsassetNames {
    String assetNames="";

    public String getAssetNames() {
        return assetNames;
    }

    public void setAssetNames(String assetNames) {
        this.assetNames = assetNames;
    }
}
```

can someone guide me on the Creation of Pojo class in retrofit in android.
If i am using the Generic type as String i am getting the response as sucess.
But when i use Custom class as Generic type.The response is fail.

Comment: Can you post your creation of Retrofit instance

Comment: Please post your retrofit code snippet also which you use to make API call.

Comment: I have posted the entire code snippet.
Please let me know anything else required.
I will post it.
Anyhow the solution I have already posted it.Below after solving it.

Answer (score 2):

I think the error is because in the response `assets` is a list of Strings and you have taken it as an object with a property `assetArray`.

Try changing `List<VoAssetGroupassets> assets;` to `List<String> assets;`.

I think a similar change needs to be done for `VoAssetGroupbeacon` and `VoAssetGroupassetsassetNames` if they are going to be Strings.

Comment: Thanks for the solution.
After the Modification to
    List<String> assets;
    List<String> beacon;
    List<String> assetNames; 
and some minor modification in 
API interface 
Call<List<VoAssetGroup>> getBeaconAssetGroup1(@Path("id") String id, @Header("ManagedAccountId") String ManagedAccountId);
The solution worked.

Answer (score 1):

The response you getting is an Array List of `VoAssetGroup`

So your call needs to be amended to

`Call<List<VoAssetGroup>> getBeaconAssetGroup1(@Path("id") String id, @Header("ManagedAccountId") String ManagedAccountId);`

Comment: Thanks for the solution.
After the Modification to
    List<String> assets;
    List<String> beacon;
    List<String> assetNames; 
and some minor modification in 
API interface 
Call<List<VoAssetGroup>> getBeaconAssetGroup1(@Path("id") String id, @Header("ManagedAccountId") String ManagedAccountId);
The solution worked.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is

API interface Modification.

```
  Call<List<VoAssetGroup>> getBeaconAssetGroup1(@Path("id") String id, @Header("ManagedAccountId") String ManagedAccountId);
```

And in the VoAssetGroup class i made this Modification.

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;

public class VoAssetGroup implements Serializable {

    String accountId="";
    String id="";
    String name="";
    String description="";


    List<String> assets;
    List<String> beacon;
    List<String> assetNames;


    public String getAccountId() {
        return accountId;
    }

    public void setAccountId(String accountId) {
        this.accountId = accountId;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public List<String> getAssets() {
        return assets;
    }

    public void setAssets(List<String> assets) {
        this.assets = assets;
    }

    public List<String> getBeacon() {
        return beacon;
    }

    public void setBeacon(List<String> beacon) {
        this.beacon = beacon;
    }

    public List<String> getAssetNames() {
        return assetNames;
    }

    public void setAssetNames(List<String> assetNames) {
        this.assetNames = assetNames;
    }
}
```